# Solve $\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty}\frac{\ln(e^{-x}-1)}{x}$ without L'Hopital or Taylor series

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty}\frac{\ln(e^{-x}-1)}{x} = \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln(e^{x}-1)}{-x} = \\
\frac{\ln(e^{x}-1)}{-x} \cdot \frac{e^{x}-1}{e^{x}-1} = \\
\frac{\ln(e^{x}-1)}{e^{x}-1} \cdot -\frac{e^{x}-1}{x} = \\
0 \cdot -\infty$$

What did I do wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: What's your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: @Chappers What do you mean?

Comment: How was the exponential function first introduced and defined to you? By a series, a differential equation, something else?

Comment: @ClementC. I don't remember exactly... I think it was as a series. I learnt about it when I learnt about compound interest I think.

Comment: hint: $\log(e^x-1)=x+\log(1-e^{-x})=x+e^{-x}+\mathcal{O}(e^{-2x})$. Also $e^{-x}/x\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @tiredNo need for the $O(\cdot)$ (which is tantamount to a first step in a Taylor expansion). The fact that $\log(1+e^{-x})\to 0$ suffices.

Comment: @MarkRead If you have defined $\exp$ with a series to begin with, it's a bit hard to fathom why you are trying to avoid Taylor series, but OK.

Comment: @ClementC. I'm not trying to avoid Taylor series, it's my book that requires me to solve this without either L'Hopital or Taylor series. Go figure... And what is $\exp$? Is it $e^x$?

Comment: $\exp(x)$ is another notation for $e^x$ (the **exp**onential function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did nothing *wrong*, but end up with an indeterminate form; so you cannot conclude with this approach.

Now, let us start from your second step: for $x> 0$,
$$\begin{align}
-\frac{\ln(e^x-1)}{x}
&=-\frac{\ln(e^x(1-e^{-x}))}{x}
=-\frac{\ln(e^x)+\ln(1-e^{-x})}{x}
=-\frac{x+\ln(1-e^{-x})}{x}\\
&= -1 - \frac{\ln(1-e^{-x})}{x}
\end{align}$$
It only remains to show the second term goes to $0$. When $x\to\infty$, we have $1-e^{-x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 1$, so by continuity $\ln(1-e^{-x})\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \ln 1=0$. It follows that 
$$
\frac{\ln(1-e^{-x})}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 0.
$$
Putting it all together,
$$
-\frac{\ln(e^x-1)}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} -1- 0 = \boxed{-1}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by writing:
$$\ln(e^{-x}-1)= \ln(e^{-x})+\ln(1-e^{x})$$
Therefore:
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\ln(e^{-x}-1)}{x}=\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\ln(e^{-x})+\ln(1-e^{x})}{x}$$
Since $\ln(1-e^x)\to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$, we have just:
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\ln(e^{-x})}{x}=\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{-x}{x}=-1$$

Comment: Not that I want to nitpick, but isn't it nearly the same proof as in my answer? (starting from the first step of the OP's question, instead of the second)

Comment: @ClementC. I figured that this way may make it more visually apparent (My solve is in a slightly different order than yours). Besides that, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: I was just wondering about the rationale (or if you actually were typing it before, which may happen). Rather ironically, I went for the limit as $x\to\infty$ because the $x\to-\infty$ case always strikes me as less intuitive and harder to "see" -- and more prone to errors. (In any case, +1)

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you. I actually was typing this before you posted your answer, however I noticed that I misread the limit so I had to make slight modifications.